# Android Databinding with LiveData - Validating multiple fields together

Tags: android-databinding, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

I am using two-way Databinding with LiveData inside a ViewModel to handle a sign-up form.

As fields are filled out, there are fields that need to be evaluated together for validity (as well as the overall form), and only enable the Submit button when everything is correct.

With a regular `Observable` object and using `@Bindable` this would be straightforward by just annotating a 'getter' function for each validation that is required and doing the necessary validation steps and return the appropriate result inside each function.

BUT I am working with LiveData. I came up with a solution using `MediatoLiveData` (see basic example below), but it seems to me like there should be another, perhaps better, approach.

```
class RegistrationViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val email: MutableLiveData<String> by lazy { MutableLiveData<String>() }

    val emailConf: MutableLiveData<String> by lazy { MutableLiveData<String>() }

    val emailValid: MediatorLiveData<Boolean> = MediatorLiveData()

    val emailChanged: (Any) -> Unit = cc@ {

        //Obviously there is more validation needed but this is just an example
        if (email.value != null && emailConf.value != null) {

            emailValid.value = email.value.isNotEmpty() && emailConf.value.isNotEmpty() && email.value == emailConf.value
            return@cc
        }

        emailValid.value = false
    }

    init {
        emailValid.addSource(email, emailChanged)
        emailValid.addSource(emailConf, emailChanged)
    }
}
```

To tie it to the UI, for example, the `enabled` property of a button or the `visibility` property of a label could be bound to the `emailValid` property appropriately.

Comment: You sound like you want to "combine" multiple LiveData just like I did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55044298/is-it-possible-to-make-one-livedata-of-two-livedatas/55044738#55044738).

Comment: Thanks, but it seems like you are doing exactly what I am doing here only with a level of abstraction. My question really was if there is another way of doing it that I was not seeing.

Comment: In that case, "not really, no".

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is correct, but code has some design issues:

- `lazy` fields is used in `init` section. Field become not lazy
- `emailValid` field can be exposed as `LiveData`
- validation can be encapsulated in inner class, but it's not required

  ```
  class RegistrationViewModel : ViewModel() {
      val email = MutableLiveData<String>()
      val emailConf = MutableLiveData<String>()

      @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
      val emailValid: LiveData<Boolean> = MediatorLiveData<Boolean>().apply {
          val validator = Validator(::postValue)
          addSource(email, validator as Observer<String>)
          addSource(emailConf, validator as Observer<String>)
      }

      private inner class Validator(private val validationConsumer: (Boolean) -> Unit) : Observer<Any> {
          override fun onChanged(ignored: Any?) {
              //Obviously there is more validation needed but this is just an example
              val email = email.value
              val emailConf = emailConf.value
              validationConsumer(when {
                  email.isNullOrEmpty() -> false
                  emailConf.isNullOrEmpty() -> false
                  email == emailConf -> true
                  else -> false
              })
          }
      }
  }
  ```

If you require some *heavy* validation, you can make *hidden mutable field* for `emailValid` and manually update it when background validation completed